# Unhanded exceptions appear in wrong place if they are thrown from async methods

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, exception, .net-core

I created .NET Core console app and added some async magic there. But somehow all exception popups from async methods appear in top-level main method (see screenshot). It makes debugging hard. How i can move them to appropriate places?

How it's now:
[image: exception]

I want to move it here:
[image]

Comment: Ever hear of `try-catch`?   Also, your async code violates many best practices

Comment: I don't want to catch these exceptions. I just want to see them in the right place.

Comment: If you **don't** catch exceptions then they will appear in the top of the stack/top-most `catch`;  _"in top-level main method "_; whichever occurs first

Comment: If you just want to see where that one happens, place a breakpoint within `MainAsync` method and see where it goes. You can see the stack trace on exception (not sure if it will be intact).

Comment: If you want the debugger to stop _when the exception is thrown_, then tick the box for **Break when xxx thrown**

Comment: @ant Normal place for unhandled exceptions? Do you mean hell?

Comment: If i create the same code without async, exception appears on the line, whet it was thrown: http://prntscr.com/fbk4h6

Comment: _" If i create the same code without async, exception appears on the line, whet it was thrown: prntscr.com/fbk4h6 – ant 10 mins ago "_ - you are **not paying attention**

Comment: Also, I'd like to know how `void Server.Run()` let's you use that with an `await` statement.

Comment: MickyD, this screenshot is from sync example.

Comment: Henk Holterman, this question is only about the way how visual studio visualize this exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger will only break when the Exception is unhandled, meaning that there is no further catch block around it. This is also where it will show up in production logs!

Async methods have an "implicit" try-catch around the function. When an exception is thrown in an async method, it is caught and only reintroduced ("re-thrown") into the call stack when the method is awaited (either via the `await` keyword or through `.Result` / `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`).
This creates a "nice" async call stack that includes the complete flow of the exception over multiple async methods.

As has been mentioned in the comments, you can set the VS debugger to break when an exception is **thrown**, but this will also break everywhere an exception is about to be handled correctly (it will break before any catch block can run).